# Get a python BeautifulSoup class name that is variable

Tags: python, html, variables, beautifulsoup, classname

I'm trying to get a variable class-name with Python and `BeautifulSoup`, which is the child of the class bar, but located in a div.

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="===>THIS IS THE CLASSNAME I WANT TO GET<===">
            <canvas ...></canvas>
<div class="bar2">
<div class="bar3">
```

Im getting the "bar" element without any problems:

```
x = item.find('div', class_="bar")
```

But how can I access the class name from the div below? I'm able to access it as a list but not as a string:

```
print(x.div.attrs)
> {'class': ['===>THIS'], [IS], [THE], [CLASSNAME], [I], [WANT], [TO], [GET<===],}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried  ``x['class']``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
x = soup.find('div', class_="bar")
print (*x.div['class'])
```

Or, if you want it in a variable:

```
x = soup.find('div', class_="bar")
l = x.div['class']
s = " ".join(l) 
print (s)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Use `select('div.bar > div:nth-of-type(1)')`*

*Example*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """ 
<div class="foo">
<div class="bar">
<div class="===>THIS IS THE CLASSNAME I WANT TO GET<===">
<canvas ...></canvas>
<div class="bar2">
<div class="bar3">
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser')

for element in soup.select('div.bar > div:nth-of-type(1)'):
    print(element["class"])
```

Prints

> ```
> ['===>THIS', 'IS', 'THE', 'CLASSNAME', 'I', 'WANT', 'TO', 'GET<===']
> ```

Comment: @tonispark let me know if this answer was helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
x = soup.find('div', class_="bar")
print (*x.div['class'])
```

is the answer I was searching for. Thanks a lot to all who contributed!

Comment: you should mark one of the above answers as correct and there is no need to repost the answer.